# Emacs elpy and web2py

Tags: python, emacs, web2py, code-completion, elpy

I have setup Python code completion by installing *elpy* from *Melpa*, and it seem to work (mostly) as advertised.

However I want it to also complete the web2py API, and I figured the best way to achieve this is to use the web2py shell, instead of the normal shell.

**0th try**

Googleing for *Emacs*, *web2py* and *auto-completion* yielded no useful results.

**1st try**

So I added to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args 
      "/path/to/web2py/web2py.py --plain --import_models --shell=myapp")
```

... did not work.

**2nd try**

Following the [elpy doc](https://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts.html#option-elpy-rpc-python-command) I realize I probably need to customize the `elpy-rpc-python-command` variable.

So I wrote this `~/bin/rpc-web2py` script such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
# note: the $@ need to relate to python becase elpy what's to pass `-W` to it.
python2.7 "$@" /path/to/web2py/web2py.py --shell=myapp --plain --import_models
```

and customized the *Elpy Rpc Python Command* to be  *Other:* `~/bin/rpc-web2py`

... still no "db." completion.

**help**

Am I approaching this problem in the right way? I am not committed to any specific code-completion solution, and am willing to have a fresh `.emacs.d` if need be.

Was anybody able to have a similar working setup?

Answer (score 3):

One obvious oversight from my part was that I didn't add the `/path/to/web2py` to my `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable, as helpfully stated by Baris's [on the code...](http://onthecode.com/post/2014/03/06/emacs-on-steroids-for-python-elpy-el.html) blog.

The other part of the answer comes from [The Web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29) by Massimo Di Pierro, that has this to say:

> #### [Using general purpose IDEs with web2py](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/14/other-recipes#Using-general-purpose-IDEs-with-web2py)
>
> The general problem with these IDEs (except those which support web2py) is that they do not understand the context in which models and controllers are executed and therefore autocompletion does not work out of the box.
>
> To make autocompletion work the general trick consists in editing your models and controllers and adding the following code:

```
if False:
    from gluon import *
    request = current.request
    response = current.response
    session = current.session
    cache = current.cache
    T = current.T
```

> The import block does not change the logic as this is never executed but it forces the IDE to parse it and understand where the objects in the global namespace come from (the gluon module) thus making autocompletion work.
>
> If you are relying on variables in your models (such as database definitions) you may consider adding to the list like this:

```
from db import *
```

> You can also consider importing all models.

```
if False:  
    from gluon import *
    from db import *  #repeat for all models
    from menu import *
```

While this is more a workaround than a solution, I will take it, and [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) that already comes as part of elpy is the logical tool to make this workaround trivial.

If somebody will come up with some less workaround-ish solution I will gladly accept that answer.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks for sharing it!